# Using VBA to extract information from Internet explorer - I'm stuck

Tags: vba

I designed some code a while ago using VBA and Excel, to check which people on my database are still VAT registered. I'm based in the UK, and I was using a European website, but because of Brexit it's no longer working!  I changed it to a British website now, and I managed to get the code to enter the VAT number from Excel into the webpage, but I can't find the Id or name of the submit button, so I'm not able to submit it. After I've submitted it I'll probably need some more help, but I'll see if anyone can help me solve this one first. Many thanks for your help. Here's the code.

```
Sub CheckVatPlayers()
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim findtext As String, player As String
     
    x = 2

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = True

    Do Until Cells(x, 1) = ""
        'If Left(Cells(x, 4), 2) <> "GB" Then
        '    Cells(x, 4) = "GB" & Replace(Cells(x, 4), " ", "")
        'End If

        IE.Navigate "https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/check-vat-number/enter-vat-details"
        Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

        IE.Document.getElementById("target").Value = Cells(x, 4).Value
        IE.Document.getElementsByName("button.govuk-button")(0).Click
        
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#

        y = 2

        For Each aEle In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("VAT registration details")
            Debug.Print aEle.innerText
             
            z = Trim(aEle.innerText)
            Cells(x, 7) = z

            If Left(z, 1) = "V" Then
                Cells(x, 7).Font.Color = vbBlack
            Else
                Cells(x, 7).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
             
            With Cells(x, 6)
                .Value = Date
                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End With
             
            y = y + 1
        Next
        x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I've indented your code for you. Next time you ask a question, please indent your code yourself. Left-aligned code is completely unintelligible and not the nicest thing to post when you expect others to read it.

Comment: That said, instead of comandeering an Internet Explorer, and cumbersomely filling in forms and scraping results, you might want to explore the possibility of getting this data from an API. There seems to be one: https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/api/service/vat-registered-companies-api/1.0

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tomalak. Thanks for indenting the code of me. This is my first post on this forum. I wasn't aware it was possible to indent it. There was no offence intended.

Comment: When I originally wrote the code, I was aware of the API. I don't have the expertise to write code to extract the information that way, and if memory serves me, if there are more than 50 requests (per month?) then I need to pay for it. My version worked well before and was free. Hopefully there's someone here with the expertise to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a government-provided API. I *really* can't imagine they are charging for it, especially not when they also provide an unlimited website free of charge. You might be lacking the expertise (yet) to talk to the API but trust me, you will be *much* better off using it, so any time you spend to find out how to do this from VBA is time well-spent.

Comment: You can still make it work though Internet Explorer, but that will be orders of magnitude slower, much more error-prone and a lot harder to maintain than doing it with API access. It may not seem like it now, but [registering a developer account](https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/using-the-hub) and moving away from IE will be worth it in the end.